# why this java regex is not working as I want?

Tags: java, regex

These are two type of string I can get in input:

```
String mex1 = "/ABCD/YY YYYYY SPA QWE XXXXX XXXXX SPA - 02342990153*XXXXX XXXX SPA ABCD LEGALI";
String mex2 = "/ABCD/YY YYYYY SPA QWE XXXXX XXXXX SPA - 02342990153*XXXXX XXXX SPA ABCD LEGALI/ORDERS/9865432342990160";
```

Which fall in two possible cases, with */some_word/some_number* and without it

I have written this regex which is giving a result I don't understand:

```
String mex=//<one of two input cases as already explained>
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(/ABCD/)(.+ )(/\\w+/\\d+)?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(mex);
if(m.find()) {      
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); 
  System.out.println(m.group(2)); // this the group I would like to retrieve...
}
```

And the result is:

```
mex2

/ABCD/
YY YYYYY SPA QWE XXXXX XXXXX SPA - 02342990153*XXXXX XXXX SPA ABCD LEGALI

mex1
/ABCD/
YY YYYYY SPA QWE XXXXX XXXXX SPA - 02342990153*XXXXX XXXX SPA ABCD
```

which is not what I expected in particular with mex2, where the string I want to retrieve get truncated.
Also, why after including the boundaries results in match find = false ?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(/ABCD/)(.+ )(/\\w+/\\d+)?$");
```

thanks

Comment: It's not truncated. Try to add couple or println statements System.out.println(m.group(3)); System.out.println(m.group(4)); and you will see.

Comment: Your second capturing group requires a space at the end therefore it stops capturing after the last space in your input.

Comment: I always get group count=3 but with mex1 group 3 is null, group 4 always raise out of bound exception.

Comment: What are you actually *wanting* to get?

Comment: I want group 2 (.+) excluding /ABCD/ at the beginning and any /word/number after if present

Comment: You mean `(/ABCD/)(.+)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your regex:

1. The `(.+ )` **requires** a space at the end of the group.
2. The `.+` is a greedy match so it matches the remainder of the string.

Try the following regex:

```
/ABCD/(.+?)(/\\w+/\\d+)?$
```

Comment: Mainly I was trying to understand why it was not working, then unfortunately, it could contain slashes :-)

Comment: @Leonardo: I've rewritten my answer.

Comment: It works actually, can you explain why I need a space in (.+<space-here>) ?

Comment: @Leonardo: In a regex, any non-special character is matched exactly. The space isn't a special character, while `.` and `+` are. Therefore `.+ ` (dot-plus-space) means "any character followed by a space" (we can ignore the parentheses since they don''t affect the matching).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
(/ABCD/)([^\/]+(/\\w+/\\d+)?)
```

The `[^\/]` will capture anything but `/`